# Luigi : Error while Parallelizing luigi task by using build function

Tags: function, build, parallel-processing, luigi

I was trying luigi multiprocessing capability by utilizing luigi.build method.
but i'm getting some library error while executing.

for next in self._add(item, is_complete):
  File "/home/manoj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 604, in _add
    self._validate_dependency(d)
  File "/home/manoj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 622, in _validate_dependency
    raise Exception('requires() must return Task objects')

here is piece of code i tried to achieve my objective.

```js
import luigi

class TaskOne(luigi.Task):
    custid= luigi.Parameter() 
    def requires(self):
        pass
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("logs/"+str(self.custid)+"_success")
    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("%s\n" % '')
        
               
class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):  
    def requires(self): 
        customersList = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
        yield luigi.build([TaskOne(custid=cust_id) for cust_id in customersList], workers=2)  
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("logs/overall_success.txt")
    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("%s\n" % "success")
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

========================================================================

Comment: In `TaskTwo.requires` you should be returning a list of `TaskOne`s instead of calling `luigi.build`. Also, check out [WrapperTask](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html?highlight=wrappertask#triggering-many-tasks), it would help you write `TaskTwo`.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you think you need to build in requires?

```
class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):  
  def requires(self): 
    customersList = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    return [TaskOne(custid=cust_id) for cust_id in customersList]
```

If you want multiple workers, you can specify this at the command line when you start your pipeline.

`luigi --module your_module TaskTwo --workers 2`

Answer (score 0):

`requires()` must return a `luigi.Task` object, or a list of `luigi.Task` objects. However, `luigi.build()` doesn't return anything. You don't need to call `luigi.build` to explicitly run the tasks, because Luigi handles running requirements on its own. The example task outlined in https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html shows the basic paradigm of how it's supposed to work.

Also, you should omit `requires()` from `TaskOne`. If it has no dependencies, then there is no need to define it.